# Convert image into binary image in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do i get binary image data in console while uploading it on server in sencha touch extjs 5? Please help

I need to save the binary data of image in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are asking image data transfer to server.
Image data converted into Base64 format first then send bas64 data through AJAX Request.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    jsonData: { fileName:"ImgfileName", fileData: imageDataInbas64},
    success: function (response, operation) {
        //success..
    },
    failure: function (response, operation) {
        //failure...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
How do convert image into Base64 format ? First i need to check the image binary format on my console while uploading a browsed image.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript

Refer the above link.
btoa() function not supported then use cross browser method